# IOS Asynchronous connection unused variable warning

Tags: ios, asynchronous

I have "unused variable" warning in below code. the last section, variable conn is unused variable. I try just 
"[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];" 
but not working. Any1 can help me?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""http://someaddress.com/webservice.php"]];
    request.HTTPMethod=@"POST";
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kod=%@",nickiminKodu];//posting parameters
    NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; yes thank you Andrei

Comment: But also read thomas' answer at the bottom. You really should put your connection in an ivar rather than just throwing it out there. Otherwise there is no way to cancel it, handle errors, or otherwise manage the connection.